# I am designing a device using a MCP73871 and I am unsure on how to connect the status pins to the ESP32 MCU

Tags: pins, diagram, schematic

I need a bit of help for my device schematic, more specifically for the status pins of the [MCP73871](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf). I am a beginner so I am trying to understand how to do it properly. The pins are PG, STAT1/LBO and STAT2. From my understanding, I can pull up both PG and STAT2 and connect them to my MCU. For the STAT1/LBO pin, if I want to use the LBO does it have to be connected to the battery?

My device will have a battery connected which is why I am using this component. I included my diagram as well.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question. "For the STAT1/LBO pin, if I want to use the LBO does it have to be connected to the battery?" <- is this the question? I'm not sure why you would get the idea that STAT1/LBO had to be connected to the battery

Comment: Is J1 where you are connecting the battery? Because you have both terminals shorted together in your schematic

Comment: @user253751 I saw an example online where someone had done that, hence my question.

Comment: @PhippsTech Yes J1 is where I am connecting the battery. Should I remove the wire in-between both wires?

Answer (score 0):

No, that pin will need to be connected to the ESP32 if you want to use it. It's just a low battery output. Be sure to pull it up to 3.3V since it's open drain if you want to use it.

Comment: Okay I see, so I can pull all 3 pins to high and have them connect to GPIOs on my ESP32. Thank you.